# Collecting Geometries using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dissolve, multipart

Objective: Convert different single part features with same attribute in a field (say 'Country') to a single multipart feature while retaining original geometries.

I have been looking for an ArcMap alternative of collect geometries tool available in QGIS 3.0+ but strangely enough, couldn't find it.

Closest match probably is dissolve tool which is identical to 'Collect Geometries' tool in QGIS as far as features (with same country name) are disjoint. For overlapping or adjacent features, it doesn't retain the original shapes and dissolve the shapes as well. I have also tried union and different other tools but no success.

I am open to ArcPy solutions as well. I hope that this image will help to understand the concept.

[image: this image]

Comment: Dissolve has a "Create multipart features" checkbox in the UI; wouldn't this accomplish your goal? Either way, your lower-right "Required" box isn't clear.

Comment: Dissolve would merge the overlapping features into a single part of the multipart feature.  Judging from the 'Required' illustration, I believe he wants to retain separate overlapping parts within a multipart feature (which seems an unusual requirement to us when we don't know the reasons why).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. Dissolve works perfect if the features are disjoint. However, for adjacent or overlapping features, original shapes aren't retained.  @Vince, "Required" shows that original shapes are retained even when the features have been converted to a single feature.

Comment: @Son of a Beach, Yes, I want to retain separate overlapping/adjacent parts within a multipart feature. The purpose is just to make features handling for surveyors, easy.

Comment: How’s your Python?   This could be done using cursors and geometry operations in a Python script.

Comment: I can say, my python experience is moderate. Which geometry operation I can use exactly? I can use cursors to find features to be converted into mutlipart but which operation will do the task on selected/found features?

Comment: It is not possible to construct topologically invalid geometries with Esri tools. Polygon rings are forbidden from overlapping  or touching at more than a point. When you Union shapes, the overlap is *always* erased. Collections are not supported, either within the same topology class or across different classes.

Comment: Thank you Vince for the answer. It's sad to know that it's not possible within Esri environment. So, that means, if I need it, I'll have to use QGIS.

Comment: You still haven't met the "if I need it" threshold. If the goal is to put lines on a piece of paper, you can change the polygons to polylines, which *can* overlap.

Comment: Actually Vince, I came across "Collect Geometries" tool in QGIS during an assignment. After going through literature, I came to know it's functionalities. I was just curious to know if we could do the same in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Vince for your comments. If you had answered the question, I would have marked it as accepted answer.

So the answer is, the requirement I stated above leads to topologically invalid polygons and Esri environment doesn't allow it. I have produced my desired output shapefile in QGIS and tried to open it in ArcMap. It opens fine but the common/overlapping area is stripped while rendering. Following image may explain the concept better. Please note that the shapefile in image has just one multipart feature having FID=0.

[image]